# почему нельзя создать пакет(package)

Tags: java, package

Создал, допустим, на диске D (ну или где угодно на компьютере) Test.java, компилю через cmd.exe, окей, открываю только что созданный Test.class, и тут проблема: если не писать package, то все ок, если писать package, то какой? И если уж написать package, то будет ClassNotFoundException (это через компиляцию с помощью cmd.exe)

Почему мы не можем создать где хотим .java файл с правильно написанным package - выдаёт ошибку!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы не читали документацию к компилятору. Создаём на диске D файл Test.java с таким содержимым:

```
package com.example;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Компилируем такой командой:

```
javac -d . Test.java
```

В рабочем каталоге появляется иерархия:

```
D:
└─── com
     └─── example
          └───Test.class
```

Запускаем такой командой:

```
java com.example.Test
```

И не получаем `ClassNotFoundException`.